# Why does parseInt("BG", 16) return 11 instead of NaN?

Tags: javascript

I use parseInt to convert string to hex value but result of `parseInt("BG", 16)` is 11. I think it must be NaN. What's happening here?

Comment: The same reason `parseInt("12abc")` returns 12. *"If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The parseInt function converts its first argument to a string, parses
>   that string, then returns an integer or NaN.

### [**parseInt**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Description)

> If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the
>   specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and
>   returns the integer value parsed up to that point. parseInt truncates
>   numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

Here in first example `B` can be parsed to integer so it returns, but in second example `G` is out of range of Hex values so it returns `NaN`

```js
console.log(parseInt("BG", 16))
console.log(parseInt("GB", 16))
```

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to `parseInt` is the radix. In base 16, "B" in "BG" corresponds to 11 (9 = 9, 10 = A, 11 = B), and G is not in the range of base 16 (which is 0-9 and A-F), so it gets ignored.

So, the result is the same as `parseInt('B', 16)`:

```js
console.log(parseInt('B', 16));
```